# Select String after string with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Imagine that we have a string like:

```
Routing for Networks:
0.0.0.0/32
5.6.4.3/24
2.3.1.4/32
Routing Information Sources:
Gateway         Distance      Last Update
192.168.61.100        90      00:33:51
192.168.61.103        90      00:33:43
Irregular IPs:
1.2.3.4/24
5.4.3.3/24
```

I need to get a list of IPs between "Routing for Networks:" and "Routing Information Sources:" like below:

```
['0.0.0.0/32","5.6.4.3/24","2.3.1.4/32"]
```

What I have done till now is:

```
Routing for Networks:\n(.+(?:\n.+)*)\nRouting
```

But it is not working as expected.

UPDATE:
my code is as bellow:

```
re.findall("Routing for Networks:\n(.+(?:\n.+)*)\nRouting", string)
```

As the @The fourth bird stated, following pattern worked for me:

```
pattern = r"Routing for Networks:\n((?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d+\n)+)(?=Routing)"
```

Comment: Split capture group 1?

Comment: What is you code? the regex looks fine but as @Thefourthbird hinted, how do you use the returned value?

Comment: There may be multiple lines of IPs, but I need exactly IPs between strings as mentioned.

Comment: I updated my question to show my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of capture group 1 included the newlines. You can split the value of capture group 1 on a newline to get the separated values.

If you want to use re.findall, you will a list of group 1 values, and you can split every value in the list on a newline.

An example with a single group 1 match:

```
import re

pattern = r"Routing for Networks:\n(.+(?:\n.+)*)\nRouting"

s = ("Routing for Networks:\n"
            "0.0.0.0/32\n"
            "5.6.4.3/24\n"
            "2.3.1.4/32\n"
            "Routing Information Sources:\n"
            "Gateway         Distance      Last Update\n"
            "192.168.61.100        90      00:33:51\n"
            "192.168.61.103        90      00:33:43")

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1).split("\n"))
```

Output

```
['0.0.0.0/32', '5.6.4.3/24', '2.3.1.4/32']
```

For a bit more precise match, and if there can be multiple of the same consecutive  parts, you can match the format and use an assertion for `Routing` instead of a match:

```
Routing for Networks:\n((?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d+\n)+)(?=Routing)
```

Example

```
pattern = r"Routing for Networks:\n((?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d+\n)+)(?=Routing)"
s = "..."
m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print([s for s in m.group(1).split("\n") if s])
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NuRzL4/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vLS2M0).

Comment: I used your code in my code as re.match(r"Routing for Networks:\n((?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d+\n)+)(?=Routing)", item2).group(1).split("\n") but I get error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: @Mahdi Did you check if there is a match first? If there is not match, re.match will return None

Comment: re.match does not find anything and returns None, but re.findall finds

Comment: @Mahdi Ok, and if you use re.search instead of re.match? `m = re.search(pattern, s)`

Comment: it is working with search, but one empty element at the end of the list is added.

Comment: the empty element just come one time, and after that I did not show that

Comment: So I will check your answer as correct. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Mahdi ow yes of course, that is because the newline at the end if part of the repetition inside the capture group. You can filter out those with `print([s for s in m.group(1).split("\n") if s])` See https://ideone.com/vLS2M0